# ! LaTeX Error: File `chronology.sty' not found

Tags: packages, miktex

I'm trying to make a time-line using the `chronology` package, but get the error:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: File `chronology.sty' not found.
> ```

Here's what I have, using an example I found on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217834/how-to-create-a-timeline-with-latex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[5]{1983}{2010}{3ex}{\textwidth}
\event{1984}{one}
\event[1985]{1986}{two}
\event{\decimaldate{25}{12}{2001}}{three}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}`
```

I can find the `chronology` file in the MiKTeX Package Manager, but I don't have the option to install it (neither do I have the option to uninstall it for that matter).

Comment: Works fine for me in a current miktex. Did you start the package manager in admin or in user mode? Which miktex version do you have?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm using it in user mode as I'm on a university computer. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Try if it helps if you synchronize (or even change) the repository (menu "Repository" in the manager).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and quickest solution is to find `chronology.sty` online and put it in the working directory with your document.  Obviously this is not a long-term (or elegant) solution, but should work.  A copy is available at:

https://yousource.it.jyu.fi/cvlab/icfp-experience-2012/blobs/410ee54c57e607886586879d3612f6cf58e8bc2e/chronology.sty

or the package dtx is at

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chronology

Chronology isn't deprecated (to my knowledge) so I don't know why it's not available for you to install.

Comment: According to CTAN, the package is available for install both with TeX Live and MiKTeX.

Comment: Agreed.  I show the same.  However, just to test I included chronology with a new document (I've never installed it before), and my miktex/texmaker did not automatically find it.  Looking into it now... ok, update: I could not install on the fly but from the package manager I could find and install it.  Peculiar.